# Empty output from AWS Batch CLI queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-batch

I defined job queues and job definitions for AWS Batch using the web console, but when I try to list them with the CLI, the output is blank JSON.

```sh
$ aws batch describe-job-queues
{
    "jobQueues": []
}
$ aws batch describe-job-definitions
{
    "jobDefinitions": []
}
```

I am puzzled because I thought I configured AWS CLI correctly. I set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, and I verified that `aws s3api create-bucket` creates buckets correctly.

Comment: Try to specify the region directly in a cli arg ex: `—region us-east-1`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Turns out the region in the AWS console where I defined everything was different from the region I selected locally.

Comment: do a `cat ~/.aws/credentials` for linux , for windows `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials` and check out your  configuration like access key id, access key, region name.